# Difference between these phrases

Tags: vocabulaire

What is the difference between:

- `on va` and `nous allons`?
- `tu vas` and `vous allez`? (in terms of how
  you'd use it in a sentence)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

---

***On* vs *Nous***

*On* (3rd singular person) is formally used to refer to an undertermined person. But in spoken French, it is used instead of *nous* which, despite the way French is taught, is viewed as formal. Both sentences are equivalent:

- *Nous allons à la plage.* (We are going to the beach)
- *On va à la plage.* (We are going to the beach)

---

***Tu* vs *Vous***

*Tu* is the 'you' singular while 'vous' is the 'you' plural. But...

Using *tu* is called ***tutoyer** quelqu'un* and is the normal way to address someone.
Using *vous* is called ***vouvoyer** quelqu'un* and is used typically when there is a kind of hierarchy or distance (a student towards a professor and vice-versa, an employee towards his boss in some companies and vice-versa, a young person towards a more aged person) or between strangers or people who don't know each other very well.

Both sentences below mean 'you arrived early this morning', but the first one uses the *tutoiement* while the other one uses the *vouvoiement*:

- *Tu es arrivé tôt ce matin*
- *Vous êtes arrivé tôt ce matin*

Comment: *Nous* as a subject has essentially disappeared from spontaneous spoken French. The only people still using *nous* in conversations are non native speakers who were taught it's "the right way"...